# Program is breaking on printf()

Tags: c, printf, embedded-linux

After the first `printf()` the program is breaking and doesn't even reaches the next `printf()`.

```
void UART_rx(void) {
    char rx_buffer[256];
    int rx_length = read(uart_filestream, (void*) rx_buffer, sizeof(rx_buffer));

    if(rx_length > 0) {
        printf("%s", rx_buffer);
        printf(" ok");
        rx_buffer[12] = '\0';
        printf(" ok");
        char str_id[4];
        char *start;
        start = strchr(rx_buffer, ',');
        start++;
        strcpy(str_id,start);
        int id;
        id = atoi(str_id);
        printf("Liczba typu int: %d, oraz jako ciag znakow: %s\n", id, str_id);
    }
}
```

Where could the problem be?

Comment: One problem is that you aren't including `\n` at the end of the prints, so the output probably isn't flushed, so you don't know where it is actually failing.  If you want to see output, make sure you terminate the line with `\n` (newline).  To be really sure, add `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: You don't validate that `start` is non-null after the call to `strchr()`.  That could cause your code to crash if there isn't a comma in the first 12 bytes of `rx_buffer`.

Comment: Show your input, please, that is, the data from `uart_filestream`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `read` call probably misses appending a null byte to `rx_buffer`, which is required by the `%s` formatter of `printf`.

Do that by adding it manually<sup>1</sup>:

```
printf("%*.*s\n", rx_length, rx_length, rx_buffer);
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Thanks to @JonathanLeffler!</sub>

**Note** that this requires `read` to read only `sizeof(rx_buffer) - 1` to prevent a buffer overflow if `read` really reads `256` bytes because then `rx_length == 256` and writing to `rx_buffer[256]` is undefined behavior.

---

Notes:

- `read` returns a `ssize_t`. Declare `rx_length` accordingly because `int` may not be able to hold values, which do fit into `ssize_t` very well.

Comment: Or, better (not least because it doesn't require altering the length of the buffer), use the original `read()` but `printf("%*.*s\n", rx_length, rx_length, buffer);` to print the buffer plus a trailing newline, limited to the length returned by the `read()` call.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Right, that's cool, will add that. I don't know much about format specifiers unfortunately. :(